# `yumdownloader --source` can't find srpm on rhel 6.5

Tags: rhel, yum

`yumdownloader --source` prints either `No Match for argument` or `No source RPM found`. Switching "Enabled" "1" or "0" has no effect.

```
[vboxuser@okdemohost ~]$ yumdownloader --source gcc
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                      |  27 kB     00:00
epel                                                                                                                                               | 4.4 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                    | 6.3 MB     00:01
rhel-source                                                                                                                                        | 2.6 kB     00:00 ...
rhel-source/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 1.6 MB     00:00 ...
rhel-source-beta                                                                                                                                   | 1.3 kB     00:00 ...
rhel-source-beta/primary                                                                                                                           |  214 B     00:00 ...
rheldvd                                                                                                                                            | 3.9 kB     00:00 ...
rheldvd/primary_db                                                                                                                                 | 3.1 MB     00:00 ...
Enabling epel-source repository
epel-source/metalink                                                                                                                               |  26 kB     00:00
epel-source                                                                                                                                        | 3.7 kB     00:00
epel-source/primary_db                                                                                                                             | 1.8 MB     00:00
No source RPM found for gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64
Nothing to download
```

repo file:

```
[vboxuser@okdemohost ~]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-source.repo
[rhel-source]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release

[rhel-source-beta]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever Beta - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/beta/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta,file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

redhat version:

```
[vboxuser@okdemohost ~]$ lsb_release -i -r
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Release:        6.5
```

repos info:

```
[vboxuser@okdemohost ~]$ yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
repo id                                                   repo name                                                                                        status
InstallMedia                                              Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5                                                                     disabled
epel                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                   enabled: 11,110
epel-debuginfo                                            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Debug                                           disabled
epel-source                                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Source                                          disabled
rhel-source                                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - x86_64 - Source                                               enabled:      0
rhel-source-beta                                          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server Beta - x86_64 - Source                                          enabled:      0
rheldvd                                                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux DVD Disk 1                                                              enabled:  3,690
repolist: 14,800
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=710469 . Looks like I should name my main repo `[rhel]` instead of `[rheldvd]` or `[InstallMedia]`

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=710469

The workaround to allow source downloads is to make a source repo name be equal to a base repo name plus "-source".

For example, to make the pre-existing repo `[rhel-source]` work, the base repo should be named `[rhel]`.